# How to get all cells from column A to reflect with a certain formula in column B

Tags: excel

[image: This is my dilema]

I am trying to get 04 18, 04 19 ... to reflect in column E from column A.
note that column A will be filled dynamically by a bot, so i need column E to grow dynamically as well.

the timestamp that the bot provides is in a string format, i want only the date and hour out of the same, because i want to plot a chart with that as the x-axis.

The formula im currently using is

```
=MID(OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTIF(A:A,"*")),8,6)
```

to get "04 18" out of "Sun Sep 04 18:19:39 UTC 2022"

Comment: Are you on Excel or google sheet? If Desktop Excel then which version do you use? Microsoft 365 may easier to apply dynamic formula.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the formula below and it works for me.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(MID(A5,9,5),2))>0,MID(MID(A5,9,5),3,1)=" ",VALUE(RIGHT(MID(A5,9,5),2))>0),MID(A5,9,5),""),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are on Microsoft-365 with latest release then can use-

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(TOCOL(A2:A100000,1),":")," ",-2)
```